# How to create native module to retrieve realm data value in react native?

Tags: react-native, realm, native-module

I've finded out almost two days to get some tutorial/refer about access realm db in react-native using native module

but no luck till now,

I've realm package in `node_modules` but I cant add `Realm.init(context)` in android folder because I don't have `import io.realm.*`

there's any way to retrieve realm database value?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You are right you need to create a native module, but I don't understand where is your error. If you don't have an import you need the library for realm.

Comment: @sfratini I've declared `include ':realm'` | `project(':realm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/realm/android')` in `setting.gradle` but im quite confuse, should i add `"io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"`  in build gradle or there's another way?

Comment: I believe I now understand. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Automatic or manual link.

1) Automatic: You just run "react-native link "npm-module"

It should do it for you. Keep in mind that it could duplicate some code if you already modify some code manually

2) Manually:

You added half of it. You need yo modify at least 2 files. One is the settings.gradle like you said, where you define the project.

It should look something like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'YourName'
include ':realm'
project(':realm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/realm/android')
include ':app'
```

Then the second part is in the app/build.gradle fie, where you need to tell gradle to actually compile the project.

Something like:

```
dependencies {
    // You would need to add this
    compile project(':realm')
}
```

You should now see the project being compiled when you bundle the project.

The second part might solve the problem that is not finding your classes. Now, the plugin might need another specific setup like adding a classpath or something like that.

Try it and post back if you have any other issue.

Comment: on the secont part, you said i need to modify 2 files (setting.gradle and build.gradle) but im quite missunderstanding, which part of code inside those files to modified?

Comment: See my edited answer. You should need to add the compile section in the dependency

Comment: My android project already declared those code above, but still cant access `Realm.init(context/this)` in `ReactContextJavaModule`, almost hopeless -_- and still cant find any tutorial to create native module to show realm value

Comment: Would you mind explaning a little more what is the context? I mean, did you make this module? Why do you say you cannot use it? Why do you believe you need to use it like that?

Comment: **my goal** is to showing realm db value in my `console.log`, but im confused to connect realm-js db in native module, also opened this case on [Realm-js github issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1502)

Comment: Alright, let's take it slow. So, you installed the module 'realm', you are making a native module, and you are importing this classes in your own native module right? So what is the problem? It says it cannot fnd the package? The class? Any other error? I want to help you but I can't fully understand nor the error nor what is going on.